# Working with large integer arrays

Tags: c, int

How to work with large integer, do I need GMP libraries or something?
I want an array that has elements starting from 0 to 2^32 
How to get this to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
unsigned int i,j=0,sz=4294967295;
unsigned int A[sz];

A[j]=0;

for(i=1;i<=sz;i++){
    A[i]=A[j]+1 ;
    j++;
 printf("%u\n",A[i]); 
}    
return 0;
}
```

error: process exited with return value 3221225725 
is it that the array is too big or something??

Comment: Why is it so big? I though you was asking about type width and what's the maximum value you can store an `unsigned int` but why such a large array? The question  title is misleading.

Comment: @iharob: I'm a little confused on that point myself.  OP seems to have multiplied the five known [Fermat primes](http://oeis.org/A019434) together to get a number approximately equal to 2^31.  I don't see the purpose of that.

Answer (score 3):

According to Google, your `A` array is [approximately 17 gigabytes](https://www.google.com/search?q=4294967295+*+4+bytes).  That's a lot.  You're probably overflowing the stack.

If you really need this much memory, you may be able to `malloc()` it instead, but on [older](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) 32-bit architectures, you're basically out of luck (address space has a hard upper limit of 4 GB, minus kernel space).

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating an array of 16-17GB which overflows the stack.
As haccks said you can try allocating on heap.

```
unsigned int *A = malloc(sizeof(int)*sz); 
if(A == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to allocate memory for array.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Don't forget to free afterwards:

```
    ...
    free(A);
    return 0;
}
```

And you also have a bug in your code. Array is indexed from `0` to `size - 1`.
This will when `i` becomes `sz` write to invalid memory.

```
for(i=1;i<=sz;i++) { // Will cause invalid memory write
    A[i]=A[j]+1 ;
    j++;
    printf("%u\n",A[i]); 
}
```

Change to:

```
for(i=1; i < sz; i++) {
    A[i] = A[j] + 1;
    j++;
    printf("%u\n", A[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Memory for arrays is allocated on stack and its size is generally small and will result in stack overflow. You need to allocate memory on heap for such a large array. Either place

```
unsigned int A[429496729];
```

out side the `main` or use dynamic memory allocation

```
unsigned int *A = malloc(sizeof(int)*sz); 
if(A == NULL)
    exit(0);
```

Use `free(A)` to free the allocated memory once you are done with `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Better use define constants from `limits.h`, such as UINT_MAX or ULONG_MAX, and check what type is used for indexing of arrays (perhaps your unsigned int transformed to int)