# creating large array in C but cant access memory

Tags: c, arrays

I am currently creating a large array that looks like this:

```
unsigned char arr[35000][500];
```

I then try to write in 256 characters into the array like so:

```
for(i=0; i < 256; i++)
{
  arr[i][0] = i;
}
```

When I do this, I get the following seg fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004007e3 in main () at arr.c:41
41        arr[i][0] = i;
```

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Comment: This is because of stack overflow. Take out of `main` or use dynamic memory allocation. Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462111/2455888) for further explanation.

Comment: char* arr = malloc(35000*500);

Comment: As @haccks said --- you are trying to allocate (roughly) 17MB of memory on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some stack overflow happening.  Consider using dynamic memory allocation